# How to Add RosterItems on ejabberd through web

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using ejabberd as a chat server for my mobile application.
And in my application we are sending contact list of mobile user to our web server than add all contacts to mobile user's roster list.
To adding all the contacts to roster I wanted to use mod_rest and trigger add_rosteritem command on  from our webserver. 
However when I add the add_rosteritem to allowed_commands ejabberd doesnt work. I couldnt find any other solution

P.S: I dont want the mobile user to add contact list to user's rosters, I want our webserver to add contacts to user's roster without getting permission from the users

Do you know any solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are on right track. But can u share the error u r getting in logs?

Comment: Actually there is no error log. When I even add the add_rosteritem command to  commands section in mod_rest configuration (ejabberd.yml). I cannot even start the ejabberd server

Comment: y do u even add to mod_rest configuration? Did u even tried running the command from ejabberdctl?

Comment: yes. When I run the command ejabberdctl add_rosteritem  it works

Comment: but mod_rest still doesnt accept add_rosteritem command

Comment: Please share the request body that you are sending via mod_rest & response too if any. And check for any logs in ejabberd debug mode.

Comment: When I add the add_rosteritem command to ejabberd.yml , the ejabberd server doesn't start.So I cannot even send the request

Comment: Please remove it from ejabberd.yml file, u don't need to add it there. And then try to send it via mod_rest.

Comment: When I remove it from ejabberd.yml , ejabberd starts but when I send the below request  
--auth admin chat.xxx.com.tr 123** add_rosteritem 905558429874 chat.meeapps.com.tr osman chat.xxx.com.tr Osman Friends both

It automaticly responds with below error:
{error,account_unprivileged}
But the account that I'm using in request is fully priviliged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution
in mod_rest configuration under
access_commands:

add

commands: all

And that works